# Pneumatic Tubes Tekkit Classic

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

I need all items (ice) to stop flowing in to my reactor when the filter isn't powered. Let's say my reactor is full on ice, but it has a slot for 32 ice. The filter pulls out a whole stack, and put's it in the reactor leaving 32 left over. Since that ice has no where to go, it gets stuck in the pipe. What I want is that when I unpower the filter, no residual items will flow back in to the reactor. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I believe a restriction pipe may solve your query... somewhat. It isn't stopping the issue from happening, but it's providing *a* solution.

The [Restriction Pipe](http://tekkitclassic.wikia.com/wiki/Restriction_Tube) basically takes an overflow and pumps it elsewhere. For example, in your situation, it would take the excess ice, and pump it back to the chest/storage it came from (if you so choose).

Comment: I ended up putting a restriction pipe connecting to an energy condenser that's converting the ice to diamonds so that it won't be building up a lot of ice.

Comment: Technically speaking, a restriction pipe acts like a really long pipe; it tricks the system to believe the distination is really far away, and as such, it ends up being the last place the item is sent.